# estimate the difference $|x(T)-y(T)|$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to estimate the difference $|x(T)-y(T)|,T=0.5$, where $$x'(t)=sin(tx)$$
$$y'(t)=ty$$
With $x(0)=y(0)=0.2$

My approach
$|x(T)-y(T)|=|0+\int_0^T sin(sx(s))-sy(s) ds|\leq$
$T\cdot max_{s\in [0,T]}(|sin(s\cdot x(s))-s\cdot y(s)|)$

Any ideas on how to continue to get a good estimate? A trivial way led me to: $diff \leq 0.5$ which feels not good enough.